# State returning NULL in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple component in which I'm trying to pass my current latitude and longitude into MapView.

If I log out `lastPosition` I get the following:

```
{
  "coords": {
    "speed": -1,
    "longitude": -122.239853,
    "latitude": 37.235444,
    "accuracy": 5,
    "heading": -1,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitudeAccuracy": -1
  },
  "timestamp" 235436345433454
}
```

So I know it's working, but why does it say null when it hits MapView in my render function?

[image]

```
export default class Map extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        coords: {
          longitude: 0,
          latitude: 0
        }
      },
      lastPosition: null,
      error: null
    }
  }

  watchID: ?number = null

  componentDidMount () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position)
        this.setState({initialPosition})
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    )
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position)
        this.setState({lastPosition})
      }
    )
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.lastPosition.coords.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.lastPosition.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you render `this.state.lastPosition` is null and all hell breaks lose. An exception is thrown and react breaks. You only set the `lastPosition` to correct data once it arrives.

You need to put a check at the point you are trying to get `coords`.

```
<MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.lastPosition ?
 this.state.lastPosition.coords.latitude : 0,
            longitude: this.state.lastPosition ?
 this.state.lastPosition.coords.longitude : 0,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
```

You probably want to show a loader while you get the data and not set it to zero. But I hope you get the point.

Comment: I'm stilling getting the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.lastPosition.coords.latitude')`

Comment: As Avi said in his answer, do you want to store the string of the json returned (you use JSON.stringify)? Just set it to `position`

Comment: I've removed `JSON.stringify()` and the map shows, but it's using 0 for the latitude and longitude.

Comment: The only reason can be that `lastPosition` did not get set to an object in `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` callback. You need to debug from here on.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSON.stringify(position) which converts the object to a string and then you store it in the state as a string.

Are you sure that this is what you wanted to do?
Because that explains why coords is undefined.